# Уменшить размер папки vendor

Tags: php, yii2

Можно ли уменьшить папку vendor?

Я создал сайт на Yii2 basic, а в нём не все плагины использовал. Она содержит более 40мб, и я там расширил на 30мб датапикер и другой для вывода диаграммы статистики. Папка vendor увеличилась до более чем 70мб. Я удалял то, что сам добавил, вроде ошибку не выдало и из композера тоже закоментировал.

Какие плагины можно ещё удалить?

Answer (score 1):

На всякий случай спрашиваю, `composer update` делали? А то, вдруг, плагины из `composer.json` закомментили, а обновить забыли.

В целом, какие плагины нужны, а какие нет, сможете определить только вы. Не известно же, что вы используете, а что нет. Можно попробовать по очереди убирать плагин за плагином и проверять функционал.

Еще один совет - можно удалить папку `vendor` вручную (бэкап сделайте, на всякий случай) и заново запустите `composer install`

Comment: да composer update сделал и все установилос каторие я хотел установить дело в том что я там ешё другие плугины тоже добавлял но неползавалас они мне ненужни хочу удалить из вендор папки

Comment: да composer update сделал и все установилос каторие я хотел установить дело в том что я там ешё другие плугины тоже добавлял но неползавалас они мне ненужни и я удалял ошибка невыдала. тепер хочу удалить ешё некаторе папки из вендор каторие при установки добавляется но незнаю можна ли так делать

Comment: Спасибо обезателно попробую удалять по очередам

Answer (score 0):

Там дерево зависимостей. 
Если не собираешься ничего дорабатывать, посмотри какие пакеты не используются в проекте и от них ничего не зависит, их можно удалить из папки.

Comment: Вот это и я сделаю. То что хотел Спасибо